# handler is invalid in a BitmapEncoder.Frames.Add call

Tags: c#, bitmapsource

I'm using this custom method to convert a Bitmapsource to a Bitmap:

```
    public Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource) {
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            using (var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(outStream)) {
                return new Bitmap(tempBitmap);
            } } }
```

this method is called several times in my code and it works great.
But when I'm calling it with a mouse click event or a key down event, i get the handler is invalid error.

I don't have any clue on how to proceed. any suggestion?

In the code I have a list of bitframes:

```
List<BitmapFrame> myImages = new List<BitmapFrame>();
```

initially the method works when I show each frame in to several pictureboxes:

```
var handler = new EventHandler(pictureBoxClick);

for (int i = 0; i < (decoder.Frames.Count); i++) {
   var picture = new MyPictureBox {
    Name = "pictureBoxFrame" + i,
    Width = (int)newWidth,
    Height = (int)newHeight,
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
    Location= loc,
    Image = BitmapFromSource(myImages[i]), };
Controls[i].Click += handler;
splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(picture);
}
```

then when I click one of these pictureboxes:

```
void pictureBoxClick (object sender , EventArgs e) {
    var selectedPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    int idx = Controls.IndexOf(selectedPictureBox);
    pictureBox1.Image = BitmapFromSource(myImages[idx]);
}
```

I get the error...

Comment: You should then post the code responsible for passing the (probably faulty) `BitmapSource`.

Comment: You said that this method is called from more than one event handler. The code in those events can be debugged, of course. Set a breakpoint there and see what is passed to the `BitmapFromSource()` method. So you have the chance to inspect your `List<BitmapFrame>` and see what it actually contains. If you post that code, it gets easier to understand what is possibly going wrong.

Comment: I don't see where you're assigning the `pictureBoxClick` handler to the `Click` event of the PictureBox controls. `int idx = Controls.IndexOf(selectedPictureBox);` → there's no reliable relation between the `List<BitmapFrame>` index and the PictureBox controls position inside the `Form.Controls` array. Also, you don't need it. You could: 1) assign the `List<BitmapFrame>` index to the `Tag` property of the PB controls in the constructor. 2) directly assign the `pictureBox1.Image = (Image)selectedPictureBox.Image.Clone()`. Anyway, you should check the content of `myImages[idx]` before using it..

Comment: I added the event handler. I don't mind about the relation between the    'code' List<BitmapFrame> 'code' index and the PictureBox controls position inside the 'code' Form.Controls'code' array. The content of each frame may change, so the software needs to reload and show all the frames again

Comment: See whether what I posted can be of use. A [sample Form](https://pastebin.com/gGAWsQBK) for testing can be downloaded from PasteBin.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your code, you are quite probably a victim of the "Stream".
Meaning that, when you are loading a resource from a [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), the stream must be available (not disposed) for the lifespan of that resource.
This applies to the image resource referenced by a [BitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2), too.
If you dispose the stream used to initialize the `BitmapDecoder`, it's Frames collection will be set to 1 frame of 1x1 size.
Since leaving the stream open is not a good idea, it is usually copied to a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.MemoryStream);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) (the raw byte array) and disposed right after.

> No matter what you might have read or heard, a `MemoryStream` does not really need to
>   be disposed (not immediately, at least), because it doesn't really use
>   any vital resources.

Having loaded an image resource from a stream, the `BitmapDecoder` can be initialized this way:

```
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memstream);
memstream.Position = 0;
BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(memstream,
                                            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                                            BitmapCacheOption.Default);
```

This way, the `BitmapFrames` of the `BitmapDecoder` will have a valid handle, because the underlying stream is still alive.
When you load a new image, the `MemoryStream` will be updated using a new `FileStream`.

To test the result of what has been written here and in the comments (those suggestions are relevant too), I've built a Test Form class.
You can [download the source code](https://pastebin.com/gGAWsQBK) from PasteBin.

Comment: Yes, i load the resource from a stream but I'm also copying the bitmap in to a new bitmap to return it before I close the streaming. Moreover, I can use this method thousand times in the code without problems.

Comment: @Federico Bianchi  Your `BitmapFromSource()` is not the problem (if you donloaded the code I posted you have seen that I used +- the same method). It's the `List<BitmapFrame>` that holds invalid frames handles when you try to assign the Bitmap → `pictureBox1.Image = BitmapFromSource(myImages[idx]);`. Since you create the initial images using the `BitmapDecoder` frames → `for (int i = 0; i < (decoder.Frames.Count); i++)` then `Image = BitmapFromSource(myImages[i])`, somewhere else those frames become invalid. Also, you refer to an Index that is unreliable `int idx = Controls.IndexOf(...)`

Comment: @Federico Bianchi  I can't see what happens in between, but the error you get is clearly stating that the handle is invalid. This happens for the reason a wrote about. You could post the whole procedure, so it can be tested to find out where and why this happens.

Comment: In your code you are not using a List<Bitmapframe> you load the image to the picturebox from another picturebox. you don't go through the same code.

Comment: @Federico Bianchi  Because it's not needed. But you could substitute the Image assignment: `pictureBox1.Image = this.CurrentBitmap;`  with: `pictureBox1.Image = BitmapFromSource(this.Decoder.Frames[this.CurrentSelectedFrame]);` and you'll have the same result, because the list of `BitmapFrames` is still part of the `BitmapDecoder`, which (for the already said reason) references valid handles. And the Frame Index is stored in the `PictureBox` objects Tag.

Comment: I need to have the frames stored into a List<bitmapframe>. I know, in the way you are doing is working. Just because you are not using that bitmapfromsource method.

Comment: @Federico Bianchi  Have you read my previous comment (and tested what's in it)? Yes, you can use `BitmapFromSource()`, passing the Decoder frame at the index pointed by the clicked PictureBox tag. Using the Decoder frames or extracting them to a `List<BitmapFrame>` is the same thing. You can do it either way, because the Decoder holds valid handles. The `BitmapFromSource()` is not the problem here. It works well if you pass it a valid BitmapSource. In your code, you're passing an invalid handle.

Comment: use your code, store the bitmapframe into a list and in the click event pass one bitmapframe from the list to the bitmapfromsource. i get the error with your code,

Comment: @Federico Bianchi  No, it doesn't, because the `BitmapDecoder` frames are referenced by valid handles. If this happens in the code you modified, there's something to fix in relation to how the `List<BitmapFrame>` is created. I've modified the code in PasteBin. It's now using a List of those objects (`private List<BitmapFrame> Frames;`). See how it's instantiated and how it's filled. You can test it and see that it's working. Also, think about whether you really need it, because the Frames of the `BitmaDecoder` are already a List of `BitmapFrame` objects. Are you sure you need another?